# MongoDB linked relation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have two tables **users** (fields: name, age) and **links** (fields: title, url, userId(ref to users)). There is a one-to-many relation between users to links. Now I want to run a query like : select * from links where user has age more than 26.

I have been trying with query like :

```
Links
    .find({title:'Chemistry'})
    .populate({
        path: 'userId',
        select: 'name.first  age -_id',
        match: {age: {$gte: 26}}
    })
    .exec( function(err,data) {
        if (err) console.log( err  );
        console.log( 'data', data);
        res.jsonp(data);
});
```

This gives me the following result :

```
[

    {
        _id: "54037d00e74f00f917e709ff",
        title: "Chemistry",
        url: "http://chemistry.com",
        comment: "Great chemo slides",
        favourites: "507",
        userId: {
            name: {
                first: "Bob"
            },
            age: 31
        },
        tags: [
            "tutorials",
            "chemo"
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: "540457f2557cded82b331ee2",
        title: "Chemistry",
        url: "http://chemistry.com",
        comment: "Great chemo slides",
        favourites: "507",
        userId: null,
        tags: [
            "tutorials",
            "chemo"
        ]
    }

]
```

Notice that the userId is null in the second object. I am not sure my query is right, but I think it should be a simple enough query for mongodb to support it. I probably don't know how to do it, do you have any idea about this ? Thanks.

Comment: What did the link document look like before population? What do the user documents referenced in the link document look like?

Comment: @wdberkeley - do u mean what model schema i have ? I am not sure if i got your question, but Link document before population has same document as above except userId object.